# SVG Sprite - hover - responsive images

Tags: svg, hover, sprite

I have the following code as part of this page - http://s1080372.instanturl.net/student/default.html.  I am using a svg sprite to display the three boxes in the middle of the page. This page is written in bootstrap.

Questions:

1. How do I include another area of the sprite as a hover image?
2. Why don't the images get smaller when I make the screen size smaller?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just update the `src` attribute to point at another area.
2. The svg images should resize if their parent divs get smaller. It's possible to do that in a number of different ways, e.g with css media-queries. The main issue seems to be that the grandparent div has a fixed width of 655px, so the three divs inside don't get any smaller than a third of that.

If the intended display area (aka *viewport*, in this case defined by the <img> element size) has a different aspect ratio than the svg view you reference, then some of the other resources in the svg may become visible, as in your example.

Here's another similar [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/linking/link-to-id.html) of what can happen if there's a mismatch in aspect ratio, the <img> viewport is indicated by the dotted border.